# how to automate the output for (1200 index) in json file with python code

Tags: python

I have the json file in my local path for text to speech

The below code gives output for only one index value. How it can be automated using for loops for 1200 indexes. Also the output file should end with "speech_1.wav", speech_2.wav... upto "speech_1200.wav" depends on the index value

Below is my code: my current code i called up for index 1 and this gives me output "speech_1.wav"

```
import json
from gtts import gTTS


def open_json(path):
    '''return a list of dictionaries
    '''
    with open('C:/Users/name/EN-63.json', 'r') as file:
        return json.load(file)

data = open_json('./data.json')

#print(data)

text = (data['datasets'][1]['transContent'])
print(text)


tts = gTTS(text = text, lang ='ta')
tts.save("C:/users/name/speech_1.wav")
print("text converted Successfully")
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Have you tried using a for a loop on the length `data['datasets']`. Also your `open_json` function is not opening the file you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `for` loop would be

```
for k, x in enumerate(data['datasets']):
    gTTS(text=x['transContent'], lang='ta').save('C:\users\name\speech_{}.wav'.format(k+1))
```

Comment: Why we use "k" and "enumerate" here. please help

Comment: `enumerate` is a built-in function which provides a running counter alongside an iterable object.  E.g., if `A=['a','b','c']`, then `for k,x in enumerate(A): print(k,x)` would print `0 a\n1 b\n2 c`.

Comment: Thank You Very much Daniel Walker

Answer (score 0):

```
length = len(data['datasets'])
for i in range(length):
  text = data['datasets'][i]['transContent']
  print(text)
  tts = gTTS(text = text, lang ='ta')
  tts.save("C:/users/name/speech_{}.wav".format(str(i+1)))
  print("text converted Successfully")
```

Hope this what do you want!